# Filters using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I set the CSS style `filter: alpha(opacity=40)` on an element in JavaScript?

Is there a special syntax I need to use, because of the parentheses in the CSS value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same as any other style:

```
node.style.filter = "alpha(opacity=40)";
```